# I am something edible, but what?

Tags: riddle

I am not a snake, but I do leave white scurf.

I am round, but I am not a ball.

Body of mine is like a pot, but I am not a pumpkin.

Who am I?

Comment: Do you think that you could [edit] this to make it a bit clearer please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the answer should be:

> Garlic (it has a white skin and is shaped like a pot, and is eatable obviously)